# Dataframe create rows from individual lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a dataframe which looks like

| Customer | ShoppingMonths |
| --- | --- |
| Jane | [1 2] |
| Rob | [0 12] |

where the shopping months is a object of months- eg Jane shops in month 1 and 2.
What i want is

| Customer | ShoppingMonths |
| --- | --- |
| Jane | 1, 2 |
| Rob | 0, 12 |

Ive tried changing datatypes and exploding the column but cant achieve the table i want.

ive created the shoppingMonths with

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    shopping_list=[]
    if row['JanShop']==1:
           shopping_list.append(1)
     .........
    df.at[index, 'ShoppingMonths']=np.array(shopping_list, dtype=object)
```

I had to turn it into a np array as i couldnt insert a list of integers to a dataframe row
thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each element in `ShoppingMonths` is a list of numbers, you can do:

```
df['ShoppingMonths'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(map(str, x)))
```